How to Identify and Apply Magento Patches Properly
I'm trying to properly identify and apply the necessary Magento patches for my setup based on the security bulletin here: APSB23-17. However, I'm struggling with a few things:

Patch Identification: The Adobe security bulletin doesn't clearly specify which exact patches should be applied, and I'm uncertain how to determine the correct patch ID based on the information provided.

Patch Application with Auto-Deployment: I have auto-deployment set up on my server. What is the recommended method to apply patches in this scenario? I haven't found clear instructions on Adobe's official site detailing the patches, their release dates, or the specific files they affect.

Using the Adobe Patch Tool: Adobe suggests using their patch module, but there's a warning about potential issues when applying a large number of patches, especially during upgrades. Why is this tool recommended if it can cause problems? What are the alternative methods?

Patch Strategy: My current Magento version is 2.4.5.p1. When I installed the patch tool, it indicated that around 100 patches need to be applied. Should I install all these patches, or would it be better to upgrade to a newer version of Magento instead?


If anyone has a clear understanding of how to properly manage patches in this context, your guidance would be greatly appreciated.
